# How to make matrix elements which spans multiple columns/rows?

Tags: equations, matrices

I have a [matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWvS5.jpg) which I would like to typeset. From the linked image, it can be seen that the bottom elements span 2 columns (and 2 rows but that's not as important), how do I typset it?

Right now I am trying this

```
\begin{gather}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        A^{-1} C & & -A^{-1} B
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
```

but it doesn't seem to work, as expected.

Comment: Try the `\Block` command from `nicematrix` package.

Comment: That did work, but I liked the solution posted by Héliton, as it doesn't include any additional library. Thanks for the insight either way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `\multicolumn`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{gather}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{A^{-1} C} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-A^{-1} B}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]